# Swift 3, unwrapping peripheral name (Bluetooth BLE)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an iOS app using Swift 3 / X-Code. This app requires bluetooth communication and I've read a few tutorials and stuff on getting it to work. So far (UI-wise) everything is working. However I'm having issues with the following, since most of the tutorials I've read are not updated to Swift 3 I believe that might be the issue here:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    //What to do when it discovers a peripheral, add it to the array list
    //print("Adding peripherals found to array: " + peripheral.name!)
    //peripheralsFound.append(peripheral.name!)
    print("Peripheral found!")

}
```

The above code has a few lines commented out, I want the peripherals found to be added to an array, however if I un-comment any line with peripheral.name! on it the app crashes with the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value"

I believe it has to do with the peripheral.name! Which was fixed by X-code itself (it added the ! or else it won't compile)
I can't make peripheral.name an optional apparently or the app won't compile and I don't know if there's any other way to get the name of the peripherals found, I'd appreciate any guidance.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optional binding to safely unwrap the optional value.

```
var peripheralNames = [String]()

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if let name = peripheral.name {
        peripheralNames.append(name)
        print("Adding peripheral found to array: " + name)
    }
    print("Peripheral found!")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! a follow up question, it seems my phone is finding 3 "No Name" devices, what would be better other than peripheral.name instead (to identify these)

Comment: The name of the device should be the main method for recognizing it. Other than that, you could use the advertisement data, but there's no other property associated with peripherals provided by this function that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default value to the print statement using ?? "..."

```
    print("Adding peripherals found to array: " + (peripheral.name ?? "name was nil"))
```

This will keep you from having to force it or you can just do a simple check with an if let

```
  if let unwrappedName = peripheral.name {
    print("Adding peripherals found to array: " + unwrappedName)
  }
```

I suggest you read about [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) and how they work so you don't have to rely on the IDE to do all the corrections for you.

Comment: In your second example it makes no sense to use the optional value with a default value instead of the result of the optional binding.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that "??" function, it seems pretty useful. What would be more recommended to display peripherals found, it seems there are 3 no name devices near me and i don't know what they are. . .

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3:
Try This

```
var arrayPeripheral: [CBPeripheral] = []
var arrayPeripheralStringName:[String] = []

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){

    let peripheralLocalName_advertisement = ((advertisementData as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "kCBAdvDataLocalName")) as? String

    if (((advertisementData as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "kCBAdvDataLocalName")) != nil){

        if !(self.arrayPeripheral.contains(peripheral)){

            self.arrayPeripheral.append(peripheral)

            self.arrayPeripheralStringName.append(peripehral.name)               

            peripheral.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```